# Do mpstat and iostat come standard with Linux RHEL 5.8?

Tags: linux, rhel

Do command line utilities like `mpstat` and `iostat` come standard with the RHEL 5.8 machine? Or are they optional utilities which the user has to install manually, if required?

I could find these utilities in my RHEL 5.5 machine but not in RHEL 5.8. So I'm confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are from sysstat.

sysstat is an optional package inside "System Tools" group. Unless it was selected during the installation, the package would not be installed.

To install sysstat, you can run following. (if the system is registered in RHN)

```
# yum install sysstat
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-enterprise-47/how-to-install-iostat-mpstat-vmstat-commands-in-rhel-3-0-a-281986/) link it appears that they are found in the `sysstat` package

Comment: SO this `sysstat` package doesn't come by default with RHEL 5.8? Why am I not able to find it in my machine?

Comment: @r9891 do you have a RHN account? if not, then no. Try find it in cdrom